# Animated .GIFs not working in IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer, animated-gif

I have created some animated .gifs which work well in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE 10. Is there any way of fixing this?
Just try looking at the below image in various browsers.

[image]

Comment: How can we test that issue? What you mean with "not working" (the gifs dissappears, or doesn't move, or are slow...)?

Comment: The .gif doesn't move but does remain visible. I presume I'm not the only person with this problem?

Comment: Well, there's various related question (you can see those on right sidebar). I suggest that you might take a look to some, perhaps they could give you a clue or directly a valid answer ;)

Comment: I didn't find any answer elsewhere, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Sorry, I think we need more data... we can't test the problem, I think that will very very useful for you to upload a testcase or something, or show us some code... something to help us. It's difficult to think a solution without see something.

Comment: Worked for me when I tested in IE 11. Opened the developer console and switched my user agents between 11,10,9,8,7 and even 5. Worked in all.

Comment: I also just tested with the developer console - it doesn't work for me with either IE, 7, 8 or 9 modes. I see the .gif but there is no animation.

Comment: Just tested with IE 11 on my own machine and it does work there!

Comment: Can you post some code or the link to the page that does not work?  It's not a problem with the actual gif, it's a problem with the code surrounding the gif.  Is the gif in an iFrame?  Is the gif being added dynamically?

Answer (score 21):

From what I can see, the issue is not your page or the animated GIF itself. It is a setting in IE10 (and other versions) on the client. You can access the setting from IE's

<kbd>Internet Options</kbd>→<kbd>Advanced</kbd>→<kbd>MultiMedia</kbd>→<kbd>Play animations</kbd>

Checking [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7cB6.png) box should yield the desired result.

But I hear the next question: **Can I detect whether my users have this box checked or not?**

Unfortunately, I could not find a way to auto-detect this condition. :-(

I guess you could put the user through a setup process (kinda like the audio/video setup screen you can access when watching HD movies) but that seems clunky.

I also checked to see of Modernizr might help, but it does not seem to. Modernizr can detect whether CSS3 animations are in play but that does not seem to correlate with this setting in IE.

Bummer.

*It goes without saying on SO, but if someone knows or finds a way to detect GIF animation capacity, please let us all know!!*

Comment: If it helps anyone else landing here, I had the same problem in IE11. The 'Play animations...' checkbox was ticked, but then I found out there was a Windows update for IE11 that fixes a problem with gif animation. Once the update was applied however, it unticked that checkbox so you then have to go back in and re-tick it. My loading spinners spin once again!