# HTML browser image compatibility

Tags: html, css

The following works in chrome but not internet explore for some reason? In internet explore the image simply doesn't appear, leaving behind that little box with an X in it that unloaded images usually have.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g_bnj37sHwEyq1a7ysCHIs8N-UwcSdaY
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GVP7J8yGCpqe_w3FRMNo4_oPStflh3jH

```
<div>
<img style="z-index: -1; position: absolute; margin-left:450px" 
src="images/penguin.gif">
<p style="color:#ff0000; text-align: center;">
</br>
</br>
</br>
This is text that</br>
appears over the image</br>
of a penguin.
</p>
</div>
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: can you share any jsfiddle link?

Comment: Try to change de doctype to <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: the X box means it doesn't find the file - try fixing your src

Comment: It functions in chrome, the src doesn't seem to be the problem unless chrome and ie use different syntax?

Comment: When looking at this page what is shown as the full path in your address bar? If you add "images/penguin.gif" directly after this full path do you see the image?

Comment: Also, any time you are having issues with HTML code, you should always put your code through a validator such as: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Lastly, also try downloading a completely different image from the Internet and see if it works. It is possible that your penguin.gif has some form of corruption in it. This is the least likely of the things mentioned previously, so check those out first.

Comment: Adding to the url and using a different image didnt work. Heres what the url looks like file:///C:/ITSC%20Labs/Lab7.htm   Also added pictures in question for context.

Answer (score 0):

Your image file is a gif Gif images are not fully supported in internet explorer:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3004241/animated-gif-file-is-not-displayed-completely-in-internet-explorer-11

> Assume that you clear the Play animations in webpages option on the Advanced tab in the Internet Options dialog box in Internet Explorer 11. When you view a website that contains animated GIF files, the animated GIF files are not displayed. A static image that is the first frame of the animated GIF files should be displayed.

> To resolve this problem, install the most recent cumulative security update for Internet Explorer. To do this, go to Microsoft Update. Additionally, see the technical information about the most recent cumulative security update for Internet Explorer.

Also see the following SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25674671

**Question:**

> I have created some animated .gifs which work well in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE 10. Is there any way of fixing this? Just try looking at the below image in various browsers.

[image]

**Answer**

> From what I can see, the issue is not your page or the animated GIF itself. It is a setting in IE10 (and other versions) on the client. You can access the setting from IE's
>
> Internet Options→Advanced→MultiMedia→Play animations
>
> Checking this box should yield the desired result.
>
> But I hear the next question: Can I detect whether my users have this box checked or not?
>
> Unfortunately, I could not find a way to auto-detect this condition. :-(
>
> I guess you could put the user through a setup process (kinda like the audio/video setup screen you can access when watching HD movies) but that seems clunky.
>
> I also checked to see of Modernizr might help, but it does not seem to. Modernizr can detect whether CSS3 animations are in play but that does not seem to correlate with this setting in IE.
>
> Bummer.
>
> It goes without saying on SO, but if someone knows or finds a way to detect GIF animation capacity, please let us all know!!

Comment: Better convert the GIF to PNG?